# How can I access plugin-specific properties of a Gradle project using the Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Many Gradle plugins define project properties. For instance, the [Base Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html) defines the properties `archivesBaseName`, `distsDirName`, and `libsDirName`.

It is my understanding that using Groovy, I'd simply access them as `project.archivesBaseName` and so on. But how can I access these properties using the typesafe Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 0):

> Many Gradle plugins define project properties

This isn't entirely true. When you do `project.someProperty`, Gradle will do an exhaustive lookup as noted [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html).

Now let's assume a very basic Java project using the Kotlin DSL:

```
plugins {
    java
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}
```

Applying the `java` plugin applies the following key plugins:

1. Applies the `JavaBasePlugin` [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/e713b5ed7e4d3f20de1a3b49e02f21f3a06f8c4c/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L269)
2. The `JavaBasePlugin` applies the `Base` plugin [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/e713b5ed7e4d3f20de1a3b49e02f21f3a06f8c4c/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin.java#L113)

As noted in the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html#sec:base_plugin_conventions):

> The Base Plugin only adds conventions related to the creation of archives, such as ZIPs, TARs and JARs

In order words, the Base plugin set defaults for all tasks that are of type [`AbstractArchiveTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html) as seen [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/e713b5ed7e4d3f20de1a3b49e02f21f3a06f8c4c/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/BasePlugin.java#L87..L126).

As of Gradle 5.5.1, those subclasses (tasks) are:

[image: subclasses that extend AbstractArchiveTask]

So back to your original question:

> how can I access these properties using the typesafe Kotlin DSL?

Simply retrieve a reference to the task you are trying to configure or reference:

```
val jar by tasks.getting(Jar::class)
println(jar.archiveBaseName.get())

val baseConvention = convention.getPlugin(BasePluginConvention::class)
println(baseConvention.libsDirName)
println(baseConvention.distsDirName)
```

The reason for the extra call for `.get()` is due to [Lazy Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html).

---

For any other third party plugin, you would need to either:

1. Grab a reference to their [extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build)
2. Grab a reference to the tasks they create

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! However, your example code seems only to work for `archivesBaseName`. Substitute `distsDirName` or `distsDirName`, and it won't compile.

Comment: Updated answer.