# How can I make typesafe accessors available for new project properties contributed by a Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

If I have a plugin which defines a new project property:

```kotlin
// Common plugin

var copyrightDate: String? by project.extra
```

And then try to access this property in a build script:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `lifecycle-base`
    id("acme.common")
}

copyrightDate = "2022"
```

I get the predictable result of:

```
e: path\to\build.gradle.kts:7:1: Unresolved reference: copyrightDate
```

A workaround [as noted in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340062/how-can-i-access-plugin-specific-properties-of-a-gradle-project-using-the-kotlin) is to explicitly declare the property again each time you are about to use it, like:

```kotlin
var copyrightDate: String? by project.extra
```

Since we have a number of projects using the same plugin, I'd rather have this happen automatically, like how applying the java plugin makes a `java {}` function available without having to declare it. This mechanism *appears* to be used by a number of plugins, including those not shipped with Gradle itself. But I'm yet to figure out how they're making it work.

How is this meant to be done?

- [Test project](https://github.com/hakanai/gradle-testkit-plugin-issue) contains a unit test written for Gradle TestKit which tries to run a similar build script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Register an extension

The official way to do this is to [register an extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#declaring_a_dsl_configuration_container).

First create an extension object. So long as it only has simple properties, it can be a [Gradle managed type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#managed_types).

```kotlin
// src/main/kotlin/my/custom/plugin/MyCustomPluginSettings.kt
package my.custom.plugin

import org.gradle.api.provider.Property

interface MyCustomPluginSettings {
  val copyrightDate: Property<String>
}
```

(I've used a `Property<>` rather than a `String` (the benefits are listed [here](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#lazy_properties)) but you could also use a plain `String` if you wanted.)

Next, in your plugin, create the extension, and set a default value for `copyrightDate`.

```kotlin
// src/main/kotlin/my/custom/plugin/MyCustomPlugin.kt
package my.custom.plugin

import org.gradle.api.*
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*

abstract class MyCustomPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
  override fun apply(target: Project) {
    val myCustomPluginSettings = target.extensions.create<MyCustomPluginSettings>("myCustomPlugin")
    myCustomPluginSettings.copyrightDate.convention("2022")
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using the Gradle Kotlin DSL. Make sure to apply [the `kotlin-dsl` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin) in your plugin's `build.gradle.kts`!

You can also apply your `MyCustomPluginSettings` in a buildSrc plugin in the same way - just use the contents of the `apply(...) {}` function in the `.kts` file.

Now when you apply your plugin, Gradle will automatically generate a [Kotlin DSL accessor](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors) from the name you gave your extension.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("my.custom.plugin")
}

println(myCustomPlugin.copyrightDate.get())
```

#### Non-extension method

If you define the property in a `.kt` file, then so long as that file is included with the plugin.

(If you're writing buildSrc plugins, then the `.kt` file can be anywhere in `./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/...`)

```kotlin
// src/main/kotlin/my/custom/plugin/constants.kt

package my.custom.plugin

import org.gradle.api.Project

var Project.copyrightDate: String?
  get() = extra["copyrightDate"] as String?
  set(value) {
    extra["copyrightDate"] = value
  }
```

Now in a `build.gradle.kts` uses can import this.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

import my.custom.plugin.copyrightDate

plugins {
  id("my.custom.plugin")
}

println(copyrightDate)
```

##### Avoiding the import

You can avoid the import by either putting `constants.kt` in the source root, without a package, or in one of the [default import packages](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#script-default-imports), like `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl`.

```kotlin
// src/main/kotlin/my/custom/plugin/constants.kt

package org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

import org.gradle.api.Project

var Project.copyrightDate: String?
  get() = extra["copyrightDate"] as String?
  set(value) {
    extra["copyrightDate"] = value
  }
```

Because of the risk of clashing, I only recommend this for buildSrc plugins. But this might be handy if you want to include a helper extension for something more complicated, like a helper function for defining dependencies with a default version (like how there's a `dependencies { kotlin("reflect") }` helper function).

Comment: Bingo, `constants.kt` seems to have been the magic I needed. We had tried to do something very similar by putting an `AcmeExtensions.kt` in `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl` but it didn't get picked up from there. A `constants.kt` even in our own package appears to be picked up.

Comment: Great! I'm not sure why `AcmeExtensions.kt` didn't work but `constants.kt` did. The filename shouldn't matter.