# Is it possible to read arbitrary values or variables defined in settings.gradle from build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to read arbitrary variables from `settings.gradle` in `build.gradle`?

Currently my `settings.gradle` is only setting the project name. This seems like a reasonable place to add some other constants that are likely to only be touched once during the project lifecycle.

I know I can create a `gradle.properties` file and set properties there, but it feels weird splitting my constants across two locations when my `settings.gradle` file is so short anyway.

Comment: This are a lots of options for this! It depends on the variables you want to share, but usually it's a good idea to use [Project Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties). These can have defaults in the project's `gradle.properties`, but can be overridden - which is very useful for CI/CD (example: [repository credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72075210/4161471)). You could also create a [convention-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72139946/4161471) that creates an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73551796/4161471).